# Is it possible to upload files larger than 2GB in Office365 through code

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, jsom

I have a form on Office365 and I need to upload documents and store them in a document library using REST or CSOM but the files are larger than 2GB. Is this possible?

If it's not possible, do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft Limitations & Boundaries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

File upload limit

> 10 GB per file for drag and drop uploads. All other upload methods have a 2 GB limit.

So using REST/CSOM I believe it falls under the 2 GB category.

Comment: 10GB drag and drop, what technology is it using to do the drag and drop, it'd be interesting if I could hijack that to bypass the 2GB limit. Unless I don't understand what they mean by drag and drop. Would it still not be ajax that makes it all work.

Comment: You can run fiddler and capture all communication to find it out :)

Comment: Good point. I'll have to investigate a bit. I find it strange that I can do 10GB through drag and drop since Drag and Drop is just a UI thing, the back end still has to be either a web service, rest or jsom right?

Comment: Yes I agree. Also I am not sure the 2GB limit is applied only while adding files using Upload Feature and not constrained with Dev.. You can give it a try first before attempting to find solutions (y)